# SXA exported HTML - asset URLs broken

Tags: sxa

Exporting an SXA 1.8 site (SC9.1) with Creative Exchange generates the static files, however the asset URLs in the exported HTML contain hyphens, whilst the folder structure from the zip file contains spaces, so the links are broken when previewing the static HTML pages.

For example:

```
<link href="-/media/Feature/Experience-Accelerator/Bootstrap-4/Bootstrap-4/Styles/optimized-min-1.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

which should refer to a folder:

```
-\media\Feature\Experience Accelerator\Bootstrap 4\Bootstrap 4\Styles
```

How can I get the exported HTML to align with the theme folder names?

I am using an IIS site mapped to the static assets, not just loading the files from disk to a browser. Site was exported as an Agency Drop.
EncodeNameReplacements is turned on in Sitecore config for spaces to hyphens out of the box, however disabling this doesn't fix the issue as the URLs with spaces still break.

Comment: Hey did we get any solution to this? my issue is little different everything is fine but somehow exported files are having "-1","-2" those unique numbers attached, so when the page is run, those items are actually does not exist as there is no such style with "-1","-2" at the end if i remove those number from generated HTML, everything works, can someone tell me from where this is being generated?

Answer (score 1):

Optimize-min files should not be exported. This might be a bug, please contact Sitecore support.

As a workaround please turn off asset optimization and try to export again:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dawid, turning off optimisation fixed the file names. Paths still have spaces but I can workaround. Will log a bug report.

Comment: Sitecore have raised a bug report. Will report back here.

Comment: have you guys found out antything? Im still having this issue